# Chrome extension content loads only for a split second

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm developing a chrome extension that involves adding a column to a table, however aside from the header the changes only load for a second before they get overridden. My changes also activate after a button within the website is pressed to load the table, but the changes always only ever take place the 2nd time the button is pressed, but never the first.

manifest.json

```
    "name": "Better Registration",
    "description": "Registration Page",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["*://*./*"],
            "js": ["content.js"],
            "run_at": "document_end"
        }
    ]
}
```

content.js

```
var run = document.getElementById("search-go");
if(run){
    run.addEventListener("click", load);
    
}


function load(){
    console.log("LOAD PAGE");
    var table = document.getElementById("table1");
    if(table != null){
        var row = table.rows[0];
        var cell = row.insertCell(9);
        cell.innerHTML = "PLACEMENT HEADER";
        for(let i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++){
            var cell = table.rows[i].insertCell(9);
            cell.innerHTML = "PLACEMENT TEXT";
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: probably something in the page you're extension is targeting is "fixing" the changes you make? Without details of the page you're trying to change, not much can be said

Comment: @Bravo What are some things I should look for in the page that could be "fixing" my changes?

Comment: javascript mainly